# Ruby on Rails loads yml file to special JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a requirements which read yml file into hash
My code is below:

```
def self.load_key
    json_obj = {}
    hsh_keys = YAML.load_file(File.open('config/locales/en.yml'))
    convert(hsh_keys, json_obj)
    p json_obj 
  end

  def self.convert(h, json_obj)
    h.each do |k,v|
      value = v || k          
      if value.is_a?(Hash) || value.is_a?(Array)
        convert(value)
      else
        json_obj.merge!({k v})
      end
    end
    json_obj
  end
```

i can not get result sucessfully.
my input file is

```
en:
  hello: "Hello %{user}!"
  en: English
  alerts:
    account:
      locked: "User account is locked."
      disabled: "User account is disabled."
```

my expected result is a json object as

```
{
      "hello": "Hello %{user}!"
      "en": "English"
      "alerts.account.locked": "User account is locked."
      "alerts.account.disabled": "User account is disabled."
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [to_json](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json). Try this:

```
hsh_keys = YAML.load_file(File.open('config/locales/en.yml')).to_json
puts hsh_keys
# {hello: "Hello %{user}!", en: English, alerts.account.locked: "User account is locked.", alerts.account.disabled: "User account is disabled."}
```

If you want to pretty print the result do this:

```
puts JSON.pretty_generate(YAML.load_file(File.open('config/locales/en.yml')))
# {
#    hello: "Hello %{user}!"
#    en: English
#    alerts.account.locked: "User account is locked."
#    alerts.account.disabled: "User account is disabled."
# }
```

Comment: I try JSON.pretty_generate with result 
"{\n  \"en\": {\n    \"hello\": \"Hello %{user}!\",\n    \"en\": \"English\",\n    \"alerts\": {\n      \"account\": {\n        \"locked\": \"User account is locked.\",\n        \"disabled\": \"User account is disabled.\"\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}" 
and .to_json will be
"{\"en\":{\"hello\":\"Hello %{user}!\",\"en\":\"English\",\"alerts\":{\"account\":{\"locked\":\"User account is locked.\",\"disabled\":\"User account is disabled.\"}}}}"
They are not my expected result.
Result will not be as you described

Comment: @huynhthinh do a `puts`. Its same as I described. I did not has your YAML file so the output is based on my expectation. However it should work. Infact `puts` for your output (from comment above) works too.

Comment: thanks, but it was not my expected result. to_json and JSON.pretty_generate just map yml data to json. it dosen't convert to new json structure.

Comment: sorry but you are not clear with your question (or maybe concept). JSON is just a serialized string. Are you trying to convert JSON string into a Ruby object?